# Gaussian kernel cosine distance

Tags: kernel-trick

I have a dataset with clustering results from $K$=3 to 70 clusters for $n$ observations. My original dataset is an $n \times m$ matrix with $n$ rows (one for each observation) and $m$ features.

I am using these data along with my clustering results to compute various metrics such as SSE, Silhouette coeff, internal density, and others to determine the number of clusters, $K$.

I am also trying a kernel based approach to find an elbow for what $K$ to pick from my dataset, by first creating a kernel matrix and then computing the above metrics. I have tried a Gaussian kernel with different sigma squared values ranging from 0.1 to 2.  When sigma squared equals 0.3 I start to see a clear elbow. This result happened when I was playing with the distance parameter of gaussian kernel. I tried this in python from a previous post as follows:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
  # this is an NxD matrix, where N is number of items and D its dimensionalites
pairwise_dists = squareform(pdist(MATRIX, 'euclidean'))    #changed euclidean to cosine here
K = scip.exp(- pairwise_dists ** 2 / s ** 2)
```

My question is, if changing the distance to cosine a valid strategy as commented in my code above, to compute the kernel matrix and then use this matrix to determine a suitable K from my dataset, or we have to stick to euclidean distance only?

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question (last sentence), it isn't entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: I just did. Hope this explains my question. If not please let me know.

Comment: It is a strategy, but you no longer have a Gaussian kernel, in fact it isn't a kernel function at that point since it doesn't integrate to one over the support.